# Python nested structure

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

I am in the process of shifting from Perl to Python, and I am struggling with what was a hash of hashes of arrays.
I have this data structure return from a REST service:

```
[
    {
      "gene": "ENSG00000270076", 
      "minus_log10_p_value": 0.0271298550085406, 
      "tissue": "Thyroid", 
      "value": 0.939442373223424
    },
    {
      "gene": "ENSG00000104643", 
      "minus_log10_p_value": 0.255628260060896, 
      "tissue": "Thyroid", 
      "value": 0.555100655197016
    }
]
```

Speaking in Perl, I'd like to parse it and have the Python equivalent of

```
${$tissue}{$value} = [$gene]
${Throid}{0.5555} = [ENSG1, ENSG2, ENSG3]
```

In Python I tried things along the line:

```
d={}
d[hit['tissue']][hit['value']].append(hit[gene])
```

but encountered various errors.

In the end, I want `d` to look like:

```
{
    'Thyroid': {
        0.939442373223424: ['ENSG00000270076'],
        0.555100655197016: ['ENSG00000104643']
    }
}
```

so grouping by tissue, then by value, and for each value have a list of genes.

Comment: No, `{'Thyroid': {0.555100655197016: 'ENSG00000104643', 0.939442373223424: 'ENSG00000270076'}}` is what OP is looking for. It states clearly isn't it..

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran: yet we disagree on what they expect. No, that's not what they want, because they expect to have a list of values per gene, not using the values as keys.

Comment: Not really. I understood it in the first go.

Comment: OP has clearly included `${Throid}{0.5555} = [ENSG1, ENSG2, ENSG3]`. So its d[tissue][value]=gene is what is expected.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran: and they also included *conflicting information* in the same question.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. @MartijnPieters is correct in that I made a mistake with the Python part. It has been a long day of trying to get my head around Python, concentration is low. I corrected it now. Keerthana is of course also correct as generally came here because I failed miserably. ;)

Comment: Take into account that floating point values are inherently *not precise*. Grouping values by a floating point value can easily lead to multiple keys for 'close' values. Should these values perhaps be normalised by rounding?

Comment: I've added expected output to your question. Can you confirm that that is now correct? I note that Keerthana doesn't match that output, and that there are more efficient and cleaner ways to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to get output of your desired format!

```
>>> l = [{'minus_log10_p_value': 0.0271298550085406, 'gene': 'ENSG00000270076', 'tissue': 'Thyroid', 'value': 0.939442373223424}, {'minus_log10_p_value': 0.255628260060896, 'gene': 'ENSG00000104643', 'tissue': 'Thyroid', 'value': 0.555100655197016}]
>>> for each in l:
...     if each['tissue'] not in res:
...             res[each['tissue']]={each['value']:each['gene']}
...     else:
...             res[each['tissue']][each['value']]=each['gene']
... 
>>> res
{'Thyroid': {0.555100655197016: 'ENSG00000104643', 0.939442373223424: 'ENSG00000270076'}}
```

Comment: Please leave a comment when you down vote stating the reason! :)

Comment: How is this going to produce a single nested dictionary? Whatever we may disagree with in the comments on the question, this is further removed from either format the OP is discussing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm sorry about that. shared the wrong code I've edited the answer!!

Comment: That still doesn't produce lists in the nested dictionary.

Comment: This is the approach that I suggest. Its upto OP to improvise it according to his need!

Comment: Glad that it helped!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`dict.setdefault()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to insert nested data structures for keys that are missing. Because that method returns either the already existing key, or the newly-inserted default value, you can *chain* these calls:

```
d = {}
for hit in list_of_hits:
    tissue, value, gene = hit['tissue'], hit['value'], hit['gene']
    d.setdefault(tissue, {}).setdefault(value, []).append(gene)
```

So for each `d[tissue]` key, ensure that there is a nested dictionary. For each `d[tissue][value]` pair of keys, ensure that there is a nested list value, and append the gene to that.

Demo:

```
>>> list_of_hits = [
...     {
...       "gene": "ENSG00000270076",
...       "minus_log10_p_value": 0.0271298550085406,
...       "tissue": "Thyroid",
...       "value": 0.939442373223424
...     },
...     {
...       "gene": "ENSG00000104643",
...       "minus_log10_p_value": 0.255628260060896,
...       "tissue": "Thyroid",
...       "value": 0.555100655197016
...     }
... ]
>>> d = {}
>>> for hit in list_of_hits:
...     tissue, value, gene = hit['tissue'], hit['value'], hit['gene']
...     d.setdefault(tissue, {}).setdefault(value, []).append(gene)
...
>>> d
{'Thyroid': {0.939442373223424: ['ENSG00000270076'], 0.555100655197016: ['ENSG00000104643']}}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(d)
{'Thyroid': {0.555100655197016: ['ENSG00000104643'],
             0.939442373223424: ['ENSG00000270076']}}
```

Do realise that floating point values can be imprecise. You may want to apply some *rounding* to normalise the values. `0.555100655197016` and `0.555100655197017` are very close together, for example, but *not equal*:

```
>>> 0.555100655197016 == 0.555100655197017
False
```

You could simply use the [`round()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) on `value`, to a number of digits that still makes sense for your application:

```
d = {}
for hit in list_of_hits:
    tissue, value, gene = hit['tissue'], hit['value'], hit['gene']
    value = round(value, 4)
    d.setdefault(tissue, {}).setdefault(value, []).append(gene)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use a mix of list comprehensions and default dicts, but I wanted to illustrate what the most simple / introductory approach would be as you're transitioning to Python:

```
output = {}
for a_dict in results:
    tissue = a_dict['tissue']
    value = a_dict['value']
    gene = a_dict['gene']
    # the `tissue` is a nested dict
    if tissue not in output:
        output[tissue] = {}
    # the genes should be an array
    if value not in output[tissue]:
        output[tissue][value] = []
    output[tissue][value].append(gene)
```

the reason why this is so verbose (compared to a Perl approach) is that Perl has some conveniences built in for creating data structures of a certain type as needed. In Python you need to use either check for the presence of the correct datastore **or** use one (of several) approaches to a dict that has default values.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the job. In fact you have almost done it

```
from collections import defaultdict
d= defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(list))
for value in values:
    d[value["tissue"]][value["value"]].append(value["gene"])
```